# Web app java in BlueMix IBM Cloud

Tags: java, web-applications, ibm-cloud

Adding a manifest file in a java project in bluemix? I have a web page that needs to store some information offline when the client does not have internet.

I am developing a web app that needs to keep the information entered by users when it is offline. On a web server, I add the manifest file that tells which items of my page have to be kept offline.

How do the same funcionalildade using Bluemix platform?

thank you

Comment: does html5 local storage fit for your case ?

Comment: Please explain in a bit more detail what it is, exactly, that you need. This isn't clear at all.